# Why does opening a connection throw a distributed transactions error in MySQL? (.NET Connector)

Tags: .net, mysql, mysql.data

I'm opening a connection to a local MySQL server and on the `connection.Open()` method it throws this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: MySQL Connector/Net does not currently support distributed transactions.
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction> transaction)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()

All I'm doing is this:

```
var connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

The connection string in the app.config is

```
<add name="Connection" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=userid;Password=password;database=dbname" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

I don't know why it's trying to enlist the transaction, I haven't specified any transactions & I only have one MySQL server I'm connecting to

Comment: What does `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString` look like? (Please sanitize any IP addresses or passwords before posting)

Comment: I've updated above with the connectionstring

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>Try adding `Enlist=false` to your connection string:</strike>

EDIT: from the [MySQL Connector/.NET documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html), if you set `AutoEnlist=false` in the connection string it should work.

```
<add name="Connection" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=userid;Password=password;database=dbname;AutoEnlist=false" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

It appears that certain versions of ADO.NET can default to automatically enlisting a connection into an existing transaction. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254973.aspx for more detail, but I expect somehow somewhere ADO is confused into thinking that there's an existing transaction going on to some other db.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: enlist
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.ValidateKeyword...

Comment: Ha, close! It's 'Auto Enlist'.  I cracked open Reflector & dug around in the MySql.Data code.  Update your answer & I'll mark it as accepted, thanks!