# Distributed transaction optional connectors

Tags: c#, mysql

We need a to run a distributed application using C#. The problem we found the .net connector with mysql does not support this. We found this devart product which claim to support it. Any one with experience using mind to share how to it works or is there any better tool?

Comment: What devart product is that?

Comment: Actually, the .Net Connector does support distributed [transactions][1].  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265734/why-does-opening-a-connection-throw-a-distributed-transactions-error-in-mysql

Comment: @AngryHacker so you mean to say AutoEnlist=false. So in my case I got 3 distributed connection any code sample for me to follow?

Comment: @AngryHacker as per my knowledge no doubt .net connector has transaction scope but does not support distributed transaction am I right?

Comment: @new14 Yes, setting AutoEnlist to false should make your distributed transaction work.  I am not sure whether it has a dependency on MSDTC - make sure to turn that on as well (including XA transactions).

Comment: @AngryHacker this I guess applies to the latest .net connector right? So must I have the msdtc you are also not sure about it?

Comment: In SQL Server world, you must have MSDTC on all the endpoints (e.g. the pc where the app is running, db server 1 and db server 2).  As far as the latest connector, I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @AngryHacker I am fully based on mysql any idea?

Comment: @new14 Afaik, the parties wanting to participate in a transaction must enlist in an MSDTC distributed transaction.  Not sure how mysql does it.

Comment: @AngryHacker looks like mysql is missing this feature I guess.